# Facebook and instagram not working afer using Cyberghost

Tags: android, facebook, instagram, vpn

I used Cyberghost to access a website that was accessible only in a specific geographic zone and everthing was working normally.
Now, I'm surprised that I cannot access facebook nor instagram via my computer or my smartphone (Android), I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error!! To do that I have to activate the VPN, how can i fix this issue?
PS: Facebook is not blocked in my country
PS 2: All the other websites work perfectly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn’t seem to be a programming question. Your question might be better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

They can tell you have a proxy and are blocking you.

You might be able to resolve it by using the pro version of cyberghost. Otherwise you are out of luck and will have to access them normally.

Comment: So if I don't use the pro version I would not be able to access them?